# PDO bindValue isn't inserting a date

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For work, i have to make an oracle database and mysql one communicate.

On Oracle, i have a `vrp` table with (among others) a DATECREATION column, in DATE format (alas, it's what SQL developer tells me when i click it). It stores dates in the DD/MON. /YY format.
[image: a screenshot of sql developer showing that the DATECREATION column is of type DATE]
[image: a screenshot of sql developer showing that the DATECREATION column hold values in the dd/mon/yy format]

I have to copy these values over to a mysql database. At first, i tried to ignore them and used them as strings; but i will have to manipulate them so i need to have them as date.

So in PHP, i do `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row[26]))` and it works fine, turning `'24-OCT-19'` into `2019-10-24`

I then try to insert this in my Mysql database, doing the following :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO [...] VALUES (?, ? [...]);
$stmt->bindValue(27, date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row[26]))); (yes there are a lot of columns)
$stmt->execute($row);
```

if i echo the data it looks fine, i didn't mixed up my indexes since the adjacents columns don't get the date inserted. However, the 27th column receives a `0000-00-00`.

No errors or warning are raised, so i don't even know how to debug this.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you not instruct oracle to pit the date correct togerther like TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )? I am also wandering, what the mysql receives when you send your insert query, but for that you must actvate the logging in mysql

Comment: i didn't precised it, but i have no rights over the oracle db. I can only select data from it. For the logging, i'm looking into it right now

Comment: this would only make a date column into text output, so it shouldn't interfere with the rights you are given.

Comment: aaaaah you mean when i select the data from it

Comment: well, your solution solves it. selecting differently was easier, hence the best solution possible, thank you. If you write it as answer i'll validate ti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your oracle select statement.

And use a following text conversion, to get a mysql date format as string

```
TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
```